# What is the point of C++/CLI?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I am wondering what the uses of C++/CLI is. It seems to me that it is basically C++ running on .Net, am I wrong in this thinking? What is it good for? Why not just use C# or some other truly managed language instead?

Comment: "Why not just use C#?" - the short answer is that C# is a light-years more powerful language for writing managed code, and you should only use C++/CLI if you MUST have its interop facilities. C++/CLI is 'deprecated' in VS2010 - intellisense was non-existent in the version I tried, whereas in VS2008 you at least had 'rubbish' intellisense. C++/CLI is 'good for' interop in the sense that galoshes are good for wading around in thigh-deep sewage. It's undoubtedly true, but at the same time you will want to get changed into a pair of trousers at the earliest possibility.

Comment: It was not deprecated. Intellisense was only left out because it was too honerous to implement. One reason could be the potential for circular includes. Considering the blurb on the Express edn installer says, C++ offers more comprehensive control, it might simply be that more classes are available via traditional #include "legacylibs.h" directives.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a couple of advantages of C++/CLI over simply C++ or say C#

- It's a great language for writing a large component which interops between native and managed code.
- Provides a fast(er) conversion path from a *purely* native C++ code base to a *purely* managed one.  Without C++/CLI your best option would be a rewrite

Comment: +1 by contrast look at the hoops you have to jump through with java to talk to gnarly bits of the OS - JNI is a real pain. I know they have improved it recently but its still not easy

Comment: and there are some DLLs that have really complex signatures that cannot be called via p/invoke, so then you have to write a wrapper in c++/cli

Comment: >that cannot be called via p/invoke< - if you are fine with unsafe code, you can consume ANY native method with P/Invoke.

Comment: I'm a bit late to this, but I would argue that instead of a fast(er) conversion path you just have a more circuitous one with the potential to end up with a code base permanently fragmented between purely managed, purely native, and this weird interop layer that just keeps growing and growing.

Comment: @logicnp You cannot. While methods having parameters of C++ types are quite hard to interop, non-standard calling conventions are simply impossible to emulate in a managed environment.

Answer (score 10):

C++/CLI has a few interesting things that C# does not have:

- Strongly-typed boxing.  If you box an `int` to an `object` in C#, you lose any information about what the original type was.  Not the case in C++/CLI.
- A distinction between destructors and finalizers.  In C# you have to manually implement `IDisposable` and remember to call `Dispose`.  In C++/CLI, you just chuck the cleanup code in the destructor (which automatically gets compiled into a `Dispose` method), and put the managed-only cleanup code in the finalizer.
- A distinction between stack and heap semantics for variables.  Stack is the default, and stack-allocated reference types will **automatically** be destroyed (disposed) - you don't have to remember to `delete` them, just let them go out of scope.  To make a long story short, it's a lot easier to deal with unmanaged resources in C++/CLI than any other .NET language.
- Function pointers.  This is less of a distinction now with anonymous delegates and lambda syntax in C#, but back in 2005 this was kind of a big deal.
- Access to **all** of the access modifiers implemented in the CLR.  You can explicitly specify public, protected or private for both the same assembly *and* external assemblies.  All you have in C# (other than the obvious `public`, `protected`, `private`) are the `internal` and `protected internal` modifiers, the former meaning "public internally, private externally" and the latter meaning "public internally, protected externally".  In C++ you can make a class "protected AND internal", which means that the member is only accessible to derived classes in the *same* assembly.
- Value classes.  Weird, but probably useful to someone!

There's a more detailed explanation of all this and more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379617(VS.80).aspx).  To make a long story short, other managed languages - C#, VB.NET, F#, and so on - do not actually give you full access to everything that the CLR can do, more like 90% of it.  C++/CLI lets you do pretty much anything you want that's in the CLR spec.

Comment: There's still no allocation of reference types on the stack, they always exist on the heap.  What you get are stack semantics, i.e. variables that are cleaned up AS IF they were on the stack.  Automatic invocation of Dispose for member variables is another place this works, though the name "stack semantics" isn't very description of that.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Yes, you're right, I wasn't really sure how to write that.  I guess "stack semantics" is as good as any, I'll change that.

Comment: "stack semantics" is also the term the compiler team uses, which is the only reason I use the phrase (since it isn't at all suggestive of member variables).

Comment: @BenVoigt: One more symptom of the fact that "stack" and "heap" are really details that shouldn't be the primary point of departure for our mental model of the language! The term "automatic variable" continues to describe the situation perfectly even in the CLI extension.

Comment: And of course ***templates***.  And argument-dependent lookup.  C++ is immensely more powerful than C#, first comment on the question notwithstanding.

Answer (score 4):

A few reasons for C++/CLI:

- it allows integration/mixing of managed and unmanaged code at a much finer level than other .NET languages
- Managed C++ wasn't particularly successful; C++/CLI was an attempt to make the .NET paradigm fit in better with existing C++ idioms
- While I don't think anyone thought it would overtake C# in popularity, I imagine that there were people who thought it would have a higher level of success than it has. Then again, for all I know it's very successful.  I haven't done anything except toy stuff with it - but when the [Visual C++ Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog) indicated that [VS2010 wouldn't have IntelliSense for C++/CLI](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx#9644735) there was a bit of a firestorm of push-back.  Much more than I expected (I'm not sure what MS expected).

Microsoft did do some things in C++/CLI that I think are interesting even if you have no interest in .NET:  the way they handled adding new keywords in a way that would least impact existing C++

- multi-word (or 'spaced') keywords (I think this technique is patented or patent-pending by Microsoft)
- contextual keywords
- 'namespaced' keywords

See [Sutter's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/hsutter/archive/2003/11/23/53519.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I doubt the technique is patented, and I doubt it will be -- it would be fairly difficult to distinguish from COBOL, which had reserved words with embedded spaces 50 years ago or so (e.g "after advancing NNN lines").

Comment: Dug it up: Patent 7496889 (http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect2=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&d=PALL&RefSrch=yes&Query=PN%2F7496889)

Comment: I'm really bet if it was tried, it would definitely be thrown out in court due to many many prior-works.

Comment: I'm not really commenting on the validity of the patent one way or the other, just mentioning that it's there. However, I do think the use of multiple words as a keyword (permitting the individual words to be used as normal identifiers) is interesting, regardless of whether it should be patentable or not.

Answer (score 2):

Gosh, I've used C++/CLI loads when you need to do something high performance (e.g. Image processing with SIMD), interop with native C++ (e.g. OpenGL code, existing legacy C++ code) or just look clever.

ok ;) Maybe not the last one

Dropping support for it would be a great loss IMO ..